# Will bigger rims raise my car height

Tags: wheels, ride-height

I currently have 14/180/65 installed, if I were to install a 15 inch rim with the factory specified tire size for the 15 inch rim would it raise my car height ? I also have 30mm lowering springs installed would it cause problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you increase the rim size, you get a lower profile tire so that the overall outside diameter doesn't change.  At the tire store and some websites this is known as your car's +1 (or +2, +3) tire size.

If you don't change the tire size you'll run into several issues from minor annoyances like the speedometer being wrong to major issues like rubbing (and subsequent blow-outs).

Comment: "from minor annoyances like the speedometer being wrong" your answer is right but please do not undervalue this. It can become a major issue if you drive (much) faster than your speedometer shows. Keep radar traps and the police in general in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of JPhi's answer, a few tire options.

180/55R15 - same width, 1.7% smaller diameter
180/60R15 - same width, 1.3% larger diameter
185/55R15 - wider, 0.9% smaller diameter
190/55R15 - wider, exact same diameter

https://tiresize.com/calculator/

Some of these sizes may be more common than others.  All of these sizes exist theoretically, but if it is not a common size, it is unlikely you will be able to find it anywhere, or you will have limited options.